# Backbone: Handle server response on create

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a view which handles a form.
This form has an event that fires up on click save button:

```
var FormView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize : function(options){
        this.collection = new PlayerCollection( {url:options.url} );
        this.collection.bind('add', this.addPlayer);
        this.collection.bind('reset', this.addAllPlayers );
    },
    saveNewPlayer : function(event){

        this.collection.create({
        name :    this.$form.find('input[name="name"]').val(),
        });
    }
});
```

(I've ommited some code not needed for this example).

This code saves correctly the new model, sending the data to the server and creating the View associated with this new model.
But I wonder how one handles server response when POSTing data to it.
For example, how I handle if server couldn't save the data or any other kind of error is found?

I'm new to backbone and I've been using jQuery since now to code my applications, so I'm used to use `success` and `error` callbacks `$.ajax` offers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Backbone offers similar callbacks, added as a second option hash to the create (and fetch and save) command, like this:

```
this.collection.create({
    name :    this.$form.find('input[name="name"]').val(),
},{
    error : function(model, response){},
    success: function(model, response){}
});
```

Comment: It might be worth adding to this answer that on your server what you want to do is respond with an http status other than 200. That's how Backbone knows to execute the error callback. So take the dataIn, validate it, authorize it, run a transaction (and maybe something goes wrong), etc. you reply with an appropriate status (400, 500, etc.) You can return from the server anything you want (like an error object with information about the error) and you can access that through your response argument.

Comment: Good comment! A good example is to use the 400-error in form validation and send the validation errors from the server for your form-handling code in backbone.

Comment: where is this documented? I'm not able to find it in http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-create

Comment: You can find it under Model.save